# Tag based policies in Apache Ranger not working

Tags: hive, apache-ranger, apache-atlas

I am new to `Apache Ranger` and the `BigData` field in general. I am working on an on-prem big data pipeline. I have configured resource based policies in `Apache Ranger (ver 2.2.0)` using ranger hive plugin `(Hive ver 2.3.8)` and they seem to be working fine. But I am having problems with tag based policies and would like someone to tell me where I am going wrong. I have configured a tag based policy in Ranger by doing the following -

```
    1. Create a tag in Apache Atlas (eg. TAG_C1) on a hive column (column C1) (for this first
 install Apache Atlas, Atlas Hook for Hive, then create tag in Atlas). 
This seems to be working fine. 
    2. Install Atlas plugin in Apache Ranger.
    3. Install RangerTagSync (but did not install Kafka).
    4. Atlas Tag (TAG_C1) is being seen in Apache Ranger when I create Tag based masking policy in ranger.
    5. But masking is not visible in hive which I access via beeline.
    Is Kafka important for Tag based policies in Apache Ranger? What am I doing wrong in these steps?
```

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is important for tagsync and for atlas too. Kafka is the one thats gonna notify rangertagsync about the tag assigments/changes in apache atlas.